# Get Pick Chooser Intent Google Drive File Documents Without Google Drive Api Integration in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, document, google-drive-android-api

I'm working on an android app which call getPickChooserIntent in google drive to get some file, It's working fine with image but not with documents:

Note: I am not talking about google drive API implementation.

```
public static Intent getPickChooserIntent(
      @NonNull Context context,
      CharSequence title,
      boolean includeDocuments,
      boolean includeCamera) {

    List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    // collect all camera intents if Camera permission is available
    if (!isExplicitCameraPermissionRequired(context) && includeCamera) {
      allIntents.addAll(getCameraIntents(context, packageManager));
    }

    List<Intent> galleryIntents =
        getGalleryIntents(packageManager, Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, includeDocuments);
    if (galleryIntents.size() == 0) {
      // if no intents found for get-content try pick intent action (Huawei P9).
      galleryIntents = getGalleryIntents(packageManager, Intent.ACTION_PICK, includeDocuments);
    }
    allIntents.addAll(galleryIntents);

    Intent target;
    if (allIntents.isEmpty()) {
      target = new Intent();
    } else {
      target = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
      allIntents.remove(allIntents.size() - 1);
    }

    // Create a chooser from the main  intent
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(target, title);

    // Add all other intents
    chooserIntent.putExtra(
        Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

    return chooserIntent;
  }
```

Get the URI of the selected image from getPickImageChooserIntent(Context)
Will return the correct URI.

```
public static Uri getPickImageResultUri(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable Intent data) {
    boolean isCamera = true;
    if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
      String action = data.getAction();
      isCamera = action != null && action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    return isCamera || data.getData() == null ? getCaptureImageOutputUri(context) : data.getData();
  }
```

after that i just find URI like:    `content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage.legacy/enc%3D8HXM7NIDpCn_Ax78iaO3nB9azNXlIu4AOk2poROCD8xP19KU%0A`

This URI working fine for image and display image in ImageView, if that time i select PDF or other documents then it's not working.

Any one have an any idea to get intent data from google drive without google drive API integration?

Thanks

Comment: What are you doing with the uri that not works?

Comment: I just want to download that file in our app.

Comment: Then show that code.

Comment: In ImageView:
 imageView.setImageURI(mUri);
PdfView:
pdfView.fromUri(mUri);

Comment: mCropImageUri ?

Comment: if image selection in google drive app it's working but if i select pdf that time uri not display in pdfView.
pdfView is 3rd part lib for display pdf in our app.

Comment: mCropImageUri means Uri .

If you have an any idea, i am very thankful to you.

Comment: You are suggesting that this has to do with your picker intent. Strange. You could have used a simple ACTION_GET_CONTENT to demonstrate your problem i think.

Comment: Can pdf viewer load from a 'normal' content scheme?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I have done via google android API integration but that time need some user permission due to this reason i just want it.

Actually in Image scenario it's working that's Why i asking here.

Comment: Yes @greenapps , it's working with local uri.

Comment: No. I mean if the user just picks a pdf file from your device instead of from google drive. Using that same intent. Then does pdf viewer display it?

Comment: Yes it's working with any other uri instead of google drive.
This is the problem, I am here to asking?
i can't access file uri of google drive.

Comment: Try to open the uri yourself and read the file contents from it. See what happens. Try to copy to device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it!

Solution:

```
 @Override
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CropImage.PICK_IMAGE_CHOOSER_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


             Uri mUri = CropImage.getPickImageResultUri(this, data);

             writeStreamToFile(getApplicationContext(),mUri,".pdf");

            }
        }
    }
```

Method:

```
   @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    void writeStreamToFile(Context mContext, Uri mUri,String ext) {
        if (mUri == null) {
            return;
        }

        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(mUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        String mCurrentPath = null;
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mCurrentPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
        }

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mCurrentPath)) {
            mCurrentPath = mUri.getPath();
        }

        File storageDir = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);

            File file = File.createTempFile("pptFiles", ext, storageDir);

            try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024]; // or other buffer size
                int read;
                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
                output.flush();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```